# Data shows n/a in a row where a value should be, why does it not show the code its supposed to show?

Tags: r, dataframe

[image: image of price guess column where values were added but for some reason one value says n/a]

```
TrainAttempt$PriceGuess <- with(TrainAttempt, 
    0+(LotFrontage*1)+(LotArea*1)+
    (MasVnrArea*1)+(BsmtFinSF1*1)+
    (BsmtFinSF2*1)+
    (BsmtUnfSF*1)+
    (TotalBsmtSF*1)+
    (GrLivArea*1) + 
    (BsmtFullBath*1) + 
    (BsmtHalfBath*1) +  
    (FullBath*1) + 
    (HalfBath+0) + 
    (BedroomAbvGr*1)  + 
    (KitchenAbvGr*1)  + 
    (TotRmsAbvGrd*1)  + 
    (Fireplaces*1)  + 
    (OpenPorchSF*1) + 
    (GarageArea*1)  + 
    (WoodDeckSF*1)  + 
    (OpenPorchSF+0) + 
    (EnclosedPorch*1) + 
    (ScreenPorch*1)  + 
    (PoolArea*1)  + 
    (MiscVal*1))
```

Comment: If any of the values of the individual variables is missing, then the sum will be `NA`.

Comment: To further what @DaveArmstrong said, you may want to investigate the `na.rm` argument in the `sum` function. `sum(1, 2, 3, NA)` is `NA` , but `sum(1, 2, 3, NA, na.rm = TRUE)` is 6.